# install command in OSX and directory structure

Tags: macos, installation, cp

I need to copy a few files to another directory. The source structure is as follows

```
src/foo1.h
src/foo2.h
src/bar/foobar.h
```

I need to copy these so they end up here

```
/usr/include/foo/foo1.h
/usr/include/foo/foo2.h
/usr/include/foo/bar/foobar.h
```

In Linux I use `cp -u --parents *.h bar/*.h /usr/include/foo` from `src`, which works great. However, I can't find a suitable replacement in Mac OSX - `cp` doesn't support `parents` or an equivalent option, and `install` supports `-d` which is supposed to preserve the structure, but gives me the following error: `install: foo1.h exists but it's not a directory`

I'm stuck. Any ideas?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3474329/how-to-emulate-cp-and-mv-parent-on-osx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [rsync](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync), e.g.

```
rsync -a ./src/ /usr/include/foo/ --include \*/ --include \*.h --exclude \*
```

BTW, you probably don't want to install stuff to /usr/include, as it may well get clobbered by system updates. Consider using e.g. /usr/local/include instead.

Comment: Definitely use /usr/local/include, not /usr/include.